# Openh264 compiling using PJSIP

Tags: android, pjsip, openh264

I am trying to build pjsip project with openh264 lib. Everything works fine except openh264 is not being detected by pjsip `./configure-android`

this is my config_site.h

```
/* Activate Android specific settings in the 'config_site_sample.h' */
#define PJ_CONFIG_ANDROID 1
#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>
#define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO 1
#define PJMEDIA_HAS_OPENH264_CODEC 1
```

I am getting following log

```
Using OpenH264 prefix... /home/user_name/PJSIPTOOLS/openh264-1.0.0/openlib/
checking OpenH264 usability... no
```

As it is not detected by `./configure-android` my app is crashing at runtime saying lib not found for openh264.

I am on ubuntu 14.04 32 bit.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Strange thing is I am able to get usability ok.. using ./configure not with ./configure-android

Answer (score 7):

I just encountered a similar issue. In the following, I refer to the directory, I downloaded and extracted OpenH264 to, as `path-to-openh264`. I created a subdirectory `android` within that folder and modified OpenH264's Makefile by setting `PREFIX=android`. Afterwards running the following commands to build OpenH264 solved the issue for me:

```
make OS=android NDKROOT=<path-to-ndk> TARGET=android-14 APP_ABI=armeabi ARCH=arm
make OS=android NDKROOT=<path-to-ndk> TARGET=android-14 APP_ABI=armeabi ARCH=arm clean
make install OS=android NDKROOT=<path-to-ndk> TARGET=android-14 APP_ABI=armeabi ARCH=arm
```

The resulting `libopenh264.so` file should end up in the directory `path-to-openh264/android/lib/`. In order to configure pjsip I used the following command:

```
APP_PLATFORM=android-14 ./configure-android --with-openh264=<path-to-openh264>/android
```

The following StackOverflow thread lead me to the right direction:

[building openh264 for android platform in x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609890/building-openh264-for-android-platform-in-x86)

The reason for this issue was, that I ran the `make install` command without the command line parameters at first. This caused the native library file to be created for the wrong ABI (the default one, which is armeabi-v7a). When building pjsip for the armeabi ABI, it didn't recognize the library, because it was built for a different ABI. At least this is what I suppose.

Comment: Thx for thous three sentences and magic words "clean" and "install" !

Answer (score 4):

Actually i faced that problem too.

Solution:

step 1:go to your openh264 directory and create a folder named "android"

step 2: open makefile and set prefix

```
PREFIX=/your_path/openh264-1.0.0/android
```

step3:then build openh264 using this command

```
make OS=android NDKROOT=/your_path/android-ndk-r10d TARGET=android-17 APP_ABI=armeabi
```

step4: now build pjsip using this command

```
TARGET_ABI=armeabi APP_PLATFORM=android-12 ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags --with-openh264=/your_path/openh264-1.0.0/android
```

hope this time you will see

```
Using OpenH264 prefix... 
/home/user_name/PJSIPTOOLS/openh264-1.0.0/openlib/
checking OpenH264 usability... ok
```

Comment: this one should be accepted answer. Thank you after 6 years :)

Answer (score 3):

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1758

- modify the "prefix" in Makefile
- run "make install ARCH=armeabi"
- run "./configure-android --with_openh264=/path/to/prefix/folder"

Comment: I have already done above step. I have following command. 
TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a APP_PLATFORM=android-19 ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags --with-openh264=/home/user_name/PJSIPTOOLS/openh264-1.0.0/openlib --with-libyuv=/home/user_name/PJSIPTOOLS/libyuv-android-master/jni --with-ffmpeg=/home/user_name/android-ndk-r10e/sources/ffmpeg-2.8/android/armeabi-v7a

It doesnt work with this command

Comment: run "make install OS=android NDKROOT=/path/to/android-ndk/ TARGET=android-21 APP_ABI=armeabi ARCH=arm" in openh264 folder.
after, run "./configure-android --with_openh264=/path/to/prefix/folder"

Comment: Tried that as well didnt work. I had to go with https://github.com/alexbbb/pjsip-android-builder project to build pjsip and I am able to do it sucessfully.