# building openh264 for android platform in x86

Tags: android, pjsip, openh264

I'm trying to build openh264 for android with following command :

```
 $ make OS=android NDKROOT=/Users/nazmulhasan/android-ndk-r10d TARGET=android-17 ARCH=x86
```

And getting the following error:

```
/Users/nazmulhasan/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.8/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: error: codec/common/cpu-features.o: incompatible target
codec/common/src/WelsThreadLib.o:WelsThreadLib.cpp:function WelsQueryLogicalProcessInfo: error: undefined reference to 'wels_getCpuCount'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
make install OS=android NDKROOT=/Users/nazmulhasan/android-ndk-r10d TARGET=android-21 ARCH=x86
```

or
    make install OS=android NDKROOT=/Users/nazmulhasan/android-ndk-r10d TARGET=android-17 ARCH=x86

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows desktop then simple install nasm. copy all nasm file into your \MinGW\bin\1.0\bin folder. and run below command.

```
make OS=android NDKROOT=/Users/nazmulhasan/android-ndk-r10d TARGET=android-21 ARCH=x86
```