# Enable video support in pjsip for IOS

Tags: ios, pjsip

I have build libyuv and lib openh264 to enable video support in pjsip, but when I configure-phone file with these two I get the following:

```
Using OpenH264 prefix... /Users/------/Desktop/pjproject-2.4.5/openh264
checking OpenH264 usability... no
Using libyuv prefix... /Users/------/Desktop/pjproject-2.4.5/Libyuv
checking for I420Scale in -lyuv... no
```

I am trying to build these two libraries for the first time. The config with which I built the libyuv is:

```
sss-MacBook-Pro:libyuv includetech$ export GYP_DEFINES="OS=ios target_arch=arm armv7=1 armv7s=1"

sss-MacBook-Pro:libyuv includetech$ export DEVPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer

sss-MacBook-Pro:libyuv sss$ export CC=${DEVPATH}/usr/bin/gcc

sss-MacBook-Pro:libyuv sss$ export CXX=${DEVPATH}/usr/bin/g++

sss-MacBook-Pro:libyuv sss$ export RANLIB=${DEVPATH}/usr/bin/ranlib

sss-MacBook-Pro:libyuv sss$ export AR=${DEVPATH}/usr/bin/ar 

sss-MacBook-Pro:libyuv sss$ export AS=${DEVPATH}/usr/bin/as

sss-MacBook-Pro:libyuv sss$ export LIBTOOL=${DEVPATH}/usr/bin/libtool

sss-MacBook-Pro:libyuv sss$ export GYP_GENERATORS=xcode

sss-MacBook-Pro:libyuv sss$ export GYP_DEFINES=system_libdir=lib64

sss-MacBook-Pro:libyuv sss$ gclient runhooks

xcodebuild -project libyuv.xcodeproj -configuration Release -arch armv7s -sdk iphoneos9.3
```

Similarly I built the openh264 following the instructions on their [github](https://github.com/cisco/openh264) page.

I have searched on google about enabling video support for pjsip, but I couldn't find any solution. 
Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: check this answer.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/34180834/5312278

Comment: The answer is for android. I am making it on iOS